# what is the flow when starting an activity

Tags: android, android-intent, workflow, workflow-activity

I have an app that starts with a main layout view (call it A). The user clicks on a buttong and it goes to a new class that manages view B. The user clicks on a button which starts a new class (C) that calls StartActivity (intent) is invoked that uses a external install app to display a file (like a image). This image is now on the screen. The user then presses the back button on the device (the arrow bent backwards).

My question is were does my app take control,

1. in C right after the StartActivity?
2. in C with a onbackPressed?
3. in B with a onbackPressed?
4. in A with a onbackPressed?
   or somewhere else?

I really want to end up in A with its main view.